# Are there any halachic problems with visiting a secular museum?

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah, tznius-modesty

When visiting a secular museum with paintings and sculptures from Egypt, Europe and Asia (usually influenced by idol worshipping ideas and if not that then elements of immodesty), are there any tips to having a fun and kosher trip to the museum?

Should such museums be avoided altogether or can one simple visit the "kosher" areas?

Comment: What's a "kosher area"? What problems do you think might exist with going to a secular museum? If you can't name any, why would you suspect any exist? (Answer these points by [edit]ing to improve your post.)

Comment: @doubleaa, already answered in the parentheses.

Comment: Answered what ? Are you asking if it's ok to go look at immodest pictures just bc it's in a museum? Are you asking for how to tell in advance where the immodest pictures are so one can avoid them?

Comment: @DoubleAA I think the question is as clear as might be desired. There are problems with visiting a museum, some of which are known to the asker and delineated in the question, which then asks how to visit a museum without any problems.

Comment: i think he's saying are you allowed to look at pagan stuff, learn about it on the placards there, etc etc. Unfortunately you can visit a museum of ancient israelite archaeology and find all the pagan symbols there as well, so i wouldn't know what to suggest.

Comment: Another consideration (for a Cohen) would be whether there are bodies/bones on display or even stored away - and in most museums there are.

Comment: @Epicentre Hmm ... Based on that, I guess a Cohen can't visit http://muttermuseum.org/ - in person, I don't mean visiting the web site :-)

Comment: Probably so @DanF . After all there are even roads Cohanim are prohibited from using (halachawise of course)

Comment: Please verify that my edited title matches your intent.

Comment: @DanF, I think we're both saying the same thing. I was just asking for "guidelines" on how to avoid "halachic problems".

Answer (score 1):

I think that [this article](http://www.ravaviner.com/2013/03/halachot-of-visiting-museum.html) answers your question as well as a bit more. 
Summary of main points:

- Art museum - It depends on the nature of the museum, and one must be certain that he will not stumble at all .
- "Body works museum" (where dead bodies are) - No, as it shames the deceased.
- Can Cohanim enter a meseum that has a mummy - Based on a leniency in Shulchan Aruch stating that Gentile dead bodies do not spread *tum'ah*, it is OK.
- Islamic Museum in Jerusalem - No, as "Islam is heresy since it claims that the Torah has been nullified. We do not strengthen those who are transgressing"
- Wax museum - No, in Israel since these are made by Jews. Outside of Israel, it is OK.
- Natural History Museum which has exhibitions about the Big Bang, Evolution, dinosaurs, etc.? - OK, "These are not issues of faith but of science.  The Maharal says that the purpose of science is to describe reality, while the Torah describes what reality should be."

See the article for details

Comment: Why does it matter that the figures in the wax museum are made by Jews?

Comment: @Daniel Did you read the article? It's explained there.

Comment: No I didn't. Could you add that piece? You have explained the reasoning for all of the other points so it would be nice to have the explanation for this point as well for consistency's sake.

Comment: That is an absolutely disgusting misrepresentation of Shulchan Arukh. (Not your fault so I'm not downvoting.) The ShA says קִבְרֵי עוֹבְדֵי כּוֹכָבִים, נָכוֹן לִזָּהֵר הַכֹּהֵן מִלֵּילֵךְ עֲלֵיהֶם; *אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁיֵּשׁ מְקִלִּין . וְנָכוֹן לְהַחְמִיר.* It is correct that a Kohein avoid going on gentile graves [because of Tumah spreading in a tent] *even though there are some who are lenient. And it is correct to be stringent.* (my translation)

Comment: @Daniel, they could chas veshalom be used as terafim?